# Using AchartEngine how can I change the color of chart values in a pie chart?

Tags: android, charts, achartengine

I am using achart engine for displaying some graphics in my application (http://www.achartengine.org/)

However for the pie chart when I set display chart values to true, I get the values but they are painted in a tone of gray that's almost invisible in the actual graphic colors.
Is there a way to change this color?

Preferably make one black and the other one white.[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I recall correctly, you can change the color of the `labels` using `setLabelsColor` function like:

```
renderer.setLabelsColor(Color.BLACK);
```

Comment: I still can't get it to do different colors bue your answer worked correctly. hehe I thought label color was for other labels.